# Split inside Align doesn't align

Tags: math-mode, align, split

I'm trying to write a set of equations and align at the '=' symbol.
I want to split the definition of some equations over multiple lines, because they are case dependent.

My problem is the split lines don't align.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A_t & = a_t + b_t \\
    B_t & = \Big\{ \begin{split}
        & A, \quad t = 0 \\
        & B_{t-1}, \quad t \neq 0
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

In this simplifies example the split definition of B is to far to the right

[image]

In my ideal output the split definition would be next to the big curly bracket. Running the same code in overleafs visual editor lets me align the way I want, but the document still looks weird.

[image: ideal_output]

I haven't found any way of doing this with align and split. If anyone knows how to make it work, or has other tools to achieve the same goal I'd appreciate it.

Comment: That is not what split is for. Why aren't you using the cases env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when in doubt, use `aligned` rather than`split`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A_t & = a_t + b_t \\
    B_t & = \Big\{ \begin{aligned}
        & A, \quad t = 0 \\
        & B_{t-1}, \quad t \neq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

Or with aligned conditions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A_t & = a_t + b_t \\
    B_t & = \Big\{ \begin{aligned}
        & A, \quad& t = 0 \\
        & B_{t-1}, & t \neq 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}


\begin{align}
    A_t & = a_t + b_t \\
    B_t & = \begin{cases}
        A, \quad& t = 0 \\
        B_{t-1}, & t \neq 0
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```